# Does (Excel) VBA Regex have an ignore case flag?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

So I know that the Excel VBA regex object has an `ignoreCase` property, but is there a way to signify this with a flag in the regex pattern? I tried `/i`, `?i`, etc. and wasn't able to find something that worked.

For example, I have:

- test
- Test
- TeSt

I'd like some pattern that can match either all three, or just "test". `test` works for the latter, but these all return no results, when I would like them to return a match for all three entries:

- `test/i`
- `(test)/i`
- `/test/i`

I currently have a checkbox on my userform that toggles `ignoreCase` but I'd like to regain that real estate if possible.

Comment: @Jeeped `[tTeEsStT]` matches a single char that is either `t`, `T`, `e`, `E`, `s` or `S`.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course; my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to use inline modifiers in VBA regex, it does not support them, nor does it use regex delimiter notation like `/test/i` since all patterns should be provided using string literals.

See the [*Constructing a Regular Expression* Micorsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ee236359%28v%3Dvs.84%29#constructing-a-regular-expression):

> In Visual Basic Scripting Edition (VBScript), a pair of quotation marks (`""`) delimit regular expressions.

Actually, these are not delimiters, but just string literal "boundaries".

Then, in the [*Flags* section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ee236360(v%3dvs.84)#flags), it is written:

> In VBScript, you can specify these flags by setting the equivalent properties to **True**.

So, no way to use the flags inside a pattern. There is also a similar mentioning of that in the [*VBScript’s Regular Expression Support* article at regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html):

> - No [mode modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) to set matching options within the regular expression.

You may programmatically or manually turn test to `[tT][eE][sS][tT]` though. Still, it will require some manipulation with the code if you want to do it dynamically.